# Are these flea droppings?

Tags: cats, fleas

This is from my cat.

Some more info about my cat, around 5-6 years old. She was a stray before I took her in - 99% of time spends inside. Is spayed. Haven't noticed overgrooming.

[image]

Thanks.

--

**Update**: Went to the vet he said it's fleas. Thought it was just dead skin or whatever. Puss wasn't too happy to get in the carrier, that's for sure. Put some medicine on her fur hopefully it will sort it out.

Comment: please edit the picture into your question and please add a bit of information about your cat like the age,gender,spayed or neutered,indoor or outdoor cat and maybe ask how to get rid of fleas in your question.

Comment: @trondhansen Thank you trond, added some more info. My question was more if that's an obvious sign of fleas that I've missed, for treatment I'll contact my vet. A small concern is that I read that some medicine for fleas are poisonous for cats so I'm taking that into account.